# There was no channel actively listening at-error to method of WCF-service

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, iis-7, svc

When trying to access the GetPostlisteArkivdeler-method of eDemokratiService.svc I get this error message:

```
Error occured   25.01.2013 19:06:07
User IP 84.49.196.18
User Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0
Url http://www.roros.kommune.no:80/Templates/eDemokrati/Services/eDemokratiService.svc/GetPostlisteArkivdeler
Referer (none)
Exception details:
HttpException: There was no channel actively listening at 'http://www.roros.kommune.no/Templates/eDemokrati/Services/eDemokratiService.svc/GetPostlisteArkivdeler'. This is often caused by an incorrect address URI. Ensure that the address to which the message is sent matches an address on which a service is listening.
Http status:
404 NotFound
Stack trace:

[HttpException: There was no channel actively listening at 'http://www.roros.kommune.no/Templates/eDemokrati/Services/eDemokratiService.svc/GetPostlisteArkivdeler'. This is often caused by an incorrect address URI. Ensure that the address to which the message is sent matches an address on which a service is listening.]
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.OnAsyncEventCompletion(IAsyncResult ar)

[Inner exception EndpointNotFoundException: There was no channel actively listening at 'http://www.roros.kommune.no/Templates/eDemokrati/Services/eDemokratiService.svc/GetPostlisteArkivdeler'. This is often caused by an incorrect address URI. Ensure that the address to which the message is sent matches an address on which a service is listening.]
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpTransportManager.HttpContextReceived(HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.HandleRequest()
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.BeginRequest()
```

The site is running on IIS7.
Here is a part of web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment>
        <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
            <add prefix="item"/>
            <!-- <add prefix="http://www.roros.kommune.no/"/> -->
        </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>

    <client>
      <!--Client configuration for the ImageEditor, the client name has to be "ImageServiceClientEndPoint"-->
      <!-- Only uncomment if the Image Service is hosted in an external application 
      <endpoint
       name="ImageServiceClientEndPoint"
       address="the address of the hosting application"
       binding="the binding the hosting application is using"
       bindingConfiguration="ImageServiceBinding"
       contract="EPiServer.ImageLibrary.IImageService" />
       -->
      <!-- Uncomment this endpoint and the "RemoteEventServiceEndPoint" to enable remote events
        <endpoint name="RemoteEventServiceClientEndPoint"
           address="soap.udp://239.255.255.19:5000/RemoteEventService"
           binding="customBinding"
           bindingConfiguration="RemoteEventsBinding"
           contract="EPiServer.Events.ServiceModel.IEventReplication" />-->
    </client>
    <bindings>
      <!-- Only uncomment if the Image Service is hosted in an external application 
      <binding type used by the Image Service>
        <binding name="ImageServiceBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000">
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="20000000" />
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </binding type used by the Image Service>
       -->
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="RemoteEventsBinding">
          <binaryMessageEncoding />
          <udpTransport multicast="True" />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <extensions>
      <bindingElementExtensions>
        <add name="udpTransport" type="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.UdpTransportElement, EPiServer.Events" />
      </bindingElementExtensions>
    </extensions>
    <services>
      <!-- In order to get fault information from the server for debug purposes, add behaviorConfiguration="DebugServiceBehaviour" to the endpoint "RemoteEventServiceEndPoint" -->
      <service name="EPiServer.Events.Remote.EventReplication">
        <!-- Uncomment this endpoint and the "RemoteEventServiceClientEndPoint" to enable remote events
            <endpoint name="RemoteEventServiceEndPoint"
                    contract="EPiServer.Events.ServiceModel.IEventReplication"
                    binding="customBinding"
                    bindingConfiguration="RemoteEventsBinding"
                    address="soap.udp://239.255.255.19:5000/RemoteEventService" />-->
      </service>

      <service name="SSP.Innsyn.Templates.Services.InnsynService">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="SSP.Innsyn.Templates.Services.InnsynServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="SSP.Innsyn.Templates.Services.InnsynService" />
      </service>

    </services>
       <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SSP.Innsyn.Templates.Services.InnsynServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="DebugServiceBehaviour">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

The website: [Link](http://www.roros.kommune.no/Politikk/Postliste/Journalpost-info1)
A working website with the same functionality: [Link](https://www.fredrikstad.kommune.no/no/eDemokrati/Postliste/Se-postliste1/#/22.01.2013/22.01.2013/)

The .svc-file is available, but not the individual methods of it.
Link to .SVC-file: [Link](http://www.roros.kommune.no/Templates/eDemokrati/Services/eDemokratiService.svc)

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: Did you figure this out at all?